# Which method to set up pay to register?

Tags: 7, users, commerce

I am building a site that requires payment, from paypal for instance, as part of the user registration. What approach should I take?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested to?

Comment: I am targeting drupal 6

Comment: Thank you; reporting the Drupal version is important, in such questions.

Answer (score 4):

Does it *have* to be registration? You might find it easier to set up one or more roles with the privileges you want to grant to paying users and then use Ubercart to grant these roles to users who buy the appropriate products.

If this sounds good, look at using the `uc_roles` module that comes with Ubercart. The Ubercart documentation contains a pretty good overview: on [selling site access with role assignment](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/10967/selling_site_access_role_assignments).

Comment: I think this is the best way to go, since with the uc_roles module you can create expiring roles and the users can still have their account, perhaps even with some diminished functionality.

Answer (score 3):

For such a use case, I would add a submit hook to the user registration form, that would save info about the user and make a redirect to the payment after registration. Either on or off site.

You should set the users to be blocked/inactive when created, and when the payment is completed, remove the block.

There are various modules for paypal which might help integrating with paypal.

Comment: You could also use roles to determine this rather than making a user completely inactive.